# Chrome getElementsByTagName returning HTMLCollection vs NodeList

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, getelementsbytagname

I've found the the JavaScript function getElementsByTagName is returning different data depending on the browser. Chrome sends back and HTML collection that is longer (really, better, IMO) than Firefox, IE or Chromium.

I'll outline my findings below. My question is essentially "Why did Chrome changes this, will other browsers do this as well (when?), and how reliable is the returned `length` attribute?"

Comparing Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.116 m)
vs. Chromium (Version 33.0.1750.152 Ubuntu 13.10 (256984)). I do notice that this Chromium build is a bit behind Chrome (v33 vs v34), so it may be heading this way as well in the Ubuntu Chromum build, but it at least helped me compare what's going on here.

Consider the following code block:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getElements(){
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(x.length);
  console.log(x);
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" size="20" id='test1'><br>
<input type="text" size="20" id='test2'><br>
<input type="text" size="20" id='test3'><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many input elements?">
</form>
```

Running the above in Chromium and other browsers gives result showing that the length is 4, and the data returned is an indexed array, something like:

`[input#test1, input#test2, input#test3, input, item: function]
0: input#test1
1: input#test2
2: input#test3
3: input
length: 4
__proto__: NodeList`

Chrome returns a similar but expanded result array:

`[input#test1, input#test2, input#test3, input, test1: input#test1, test2: input#test2, test3: input#test3, item: function, namedItem: function]
0: input#test1
1: input#test2
2: input#test3
3: input
length: 4
test1: input#test1
test2: input#test2
test3: input#test3
__proto__: HTMLCollection`

Notice that in both cases, the length is 4, but Chromium includes each input element a second time, indexed by the element's ID attribute instead of the index key. Chrome is returning an *HTMLCollection* where Chromium supplies a *NodeList*.

In the past I've processed these arrays with `for x in y` syntax, plus some validation, like so:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x in inputs){
  if(inputs[x].id != undefined){
  }
}
```

The conclusion I've drawn is that to use the results this way:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x=0; x<inputs.length; x++){
}
```

Either way, you access your elements with `inputs[x]` but using the second method we guarantee that `x` is always one of the integers that we use as a key. In the first method, x would be an integer-key, then the string 'length', then any ID strings.

Comment: This is interesting but is it a question ?

Comment: I almost posted without a question at all... but paragraph two is my question, "Why did Chrome changes this, will other browsers do this as well (when?), and how reliable is the returned length attribute?"

Comment: Note that `for (attr in obj)` iterates all properties, even those which were inherited due to the prototype chain. It's therefore recommendable to use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/603003).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the developer [firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName):

> While the W3C DOM 3 Core specification says elements is a NodeList
>   that was simply because of a an attempt to have the "core"
>   specification not depend on the "html" specification at that time. The
>   DOM 4 draft says that elements is an HTMLCollection.
>
> Gecko/Firefox currently returns a NodeList (Bug 162927) but starting
>   with Gecko/Firefox 19, this method will return HTMLCollection (Bug
>   799464). Internet Explorer returns a HTMLCollection. WebKit returns a
>   NodeList. Opera also returns a NodeList, but with a namedItem method
>   implemented, which makes it similar to a HTMLCollection.